# Argument 1 passed to ...LeadRep::create() must be an instance of ...Entities\Lead, array given, called in .....LeadController.php on line 108

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, doctrine

I have tried to insert lead_name,lead_status,lead_description value in db in laravel 6.18.41 version.

Controller code(LeadController.php):

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repository\LeadRep as LeadRepo;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\BaseController as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;

class LeadController extends BaseController
{
    private $leadRepo;

    public function __construct(LeadRepo $leadRepo)
    {
        $this->leadRepo = $leadRepo;
    }
    /**
    * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
    */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'App\Entities\Lead'
        ));
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function index()
    {
        //$started = microtime(true);
        $count = $this->leadRepo->count();
        //$end = microtime(true);
        //$queryTime = $end - $started;
        $lead = $this->leadRepo->findAll();


        if (is_null($lead)) {

            return $this->sendError('Lead not found.');

        }
        $serializer = new Serializer(array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer()), array('json' => new
        JsonEncoder()));
        $json = $serializer->serialize($lead, 'json');

        return $this->sendResponse($json, 'Leads retrieved successfully.');
        //return $this->sendResponse($count . "<-count ... querytime -> " . $queryTime . " ms", 'Leads retrieved successfully.');

    }
 

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function store(Request $request)

    { 
        $input = $request->all();
        


        
        // $validatedData = $request -> validate([

        //     'lead_name' => 'required',

        //     'lead_status' => 'required',

        //     'lead_description' => 'required'

        // ]);



        /*$validator = Validator::make($input, [

            'lead_name' => 'required',

            'lead_status' => 'required',

            'lead_description' => 'required'

        ]);*/


        /*if ($validator->fails()) {

            return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validator->errors());

        }*/

        //$input = $request->all();
        Log::info($input);


        //$lead = Lead::create($input);
        $lead = $this->leadRepo->create($input);


        return $this->sendResponse($lead, 'Lead created successfully.');

    }


    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function show($id)

    {

        $lead = $this->leadRepo->findById($id);

        Log::info(print_r($lead,true));

        if (is_null($lead)) {

            return $this->sendError('Lead not found.');

        }

        $serializer = new Serializer(array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer()), array('json' => new
        JsonEncoder()));
        $json = $serializer->serialize($lead, 'json');

        return $this->sendResponse($json,
            'Lead retrieved successfully.');

    }


    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param Lead $lead
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function update(Request $request, Lead $lead)

    {

        $input = $request->all();


        $validator = Validator::make($input, [
            'id' => 'required',

            'lead_name' => 'required',

            'lead_status' => 'required',

            'lead_description' => 'required'

        ]);


        if ($validator->fails()) {

            return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validator->errors());

        }

        $lead = $this->leadRepo->findById($input['id']);

        if (is_null($lead)) {

            return $this->sendError('Lead cannot be updated. Lead Id not found.');

        }

        $lead->lead_name = $input['lead_name'];

        $lead->lead_status = $input['lead_status'];

        $lead->lead_description = $input['lead_description'];

        $lead = $this->leadRepo->create($lead);


        return $this->sendResponse([], 'Lead updated successfully.');

    }


    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function destroy(Lead $lead)

    {

        //$lead->delete();
        return $this->sendResponse([], 'Lead deleted successfully.');

    }

}
```

**Lead Entity(Lead.php):**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entities;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JsonSerializable;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity @ORM\Table(name="lead")
 */
class Lead
{
    /** @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer") @ORM\GeneratedValue */
    protected $id;
    /** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
    protected $lead_name;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
    protected $lead_status;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
    protected $lead_description;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getLeadName()
    {
        return $this->lead_name;
    }

    public function setLeadName($lead_name)
    {
        $this->lead_name = $lead_name;
    }
    public function getLeadStatus()
    {
        return $this->lead_status;
    }

    public function setLeadStatus($lead_status)
    {
        $this->lead_status = $lead_status;
    }
    public function getLeadDescription()
    {
        return $this->lead_description;
    }

    public function setLeadDescription($lead_description)
    {
        $this->lead_description = $lead_description;
    }
}
```

**Lead Repository(LeadRep.php):**

```
<?php
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entities\Lead;
use App\Entities\Post;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;


/**
 * Class LeadRep
 * @package App\Repository
 */
class LeadRep {
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $class = 'App\Entities\Lead';

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;


    /**
     * LeadRep constructor.
     * @param EntityManager $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @param Lead $lead
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException
     */
    public function create(Lead $lead)
    {
        $this->em->persist($lead);
        $this->em->flush();
    }

    /**
     * @param Lead $lead
     * @param $data
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException
     */
    public function update(Lead $lead, $data)
    {
        $lead->setLeadDescription($data['lead_description']);
        $lead->setLeadName($data['lead_name']);
        $lead->getLeadStatus($data['lead_status']);
        $this->em->persist($lead);
        $this->em->flush();
    }

    /**
     * @param $id
     * @return object|null
     */
    public function findById($id)
    {
        Log::info("Id info".$id);
        return $this->em->getRepository($this->class)->findOneBy([
            'id' => $id
        ]);
    }

    public function findAll()
    {
        return $this->em->getRepository($this->class)->findAll();
    }

    public function count()
    {
        $criteria = [];
        return $this->em->getRepository($this->class)->count($criteria);
    }

    /**
     * @param Lead $lead
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException
     */
    public function delete(Lead $lead)
    {
        $this->em->remove($lead);
        $this->em->flush();
    }

    /**
     * @param $data
     * @return Lead
     */
    public function prepareData($data)
    {
        return new Lead($data);
    }
}
```

**Web Route:**

```
 use App\Http\Controllers\Lead;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
  

Route::get('lead/{key}','LeadController@show'); 

Route::get('lead_all','LeadController@index'); 

/*Route::get('create_lead/{lead_name}/{lead_status?}/{lead_description?}',function () {
    return view('leadview');
});*/ 

Route::post('lead_create','LeadController@store'); 

Route::get('create_lead',function () {
    return view('leadview');
});

Route::get('student/{key}','StudentController@show'); 

Route::get('student_all','StudentController@index');
```

**Blade View file(leadview.blade.php):**

```
<form method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/lead_create" accept-charset="UTF-8"> 
@csrf <!-- {{ csrf_field() }} -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 ">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">Your lead_name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="" name="lead_name" type="text" id="name"> 
                   
</div>

                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 ">
            <label for="email" class="control-label">Your lead_status</label>
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="" name="lead_status" type="text" id="email"> 
                   
</div>

                        <div class="form-group col-lg-12 ">
            <label for="message" class="control-label">Your lead_description</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="" name="lead_description" cols="50" rows="10" id="message"></textarea> 
                   
</div>

                        
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
   <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Send">
</div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I have used doctine with laravel in this project.When submit the form to insert lead value from from,it returning below error,
`Argument 1 passed to App\Repository\LeadRep::create() must be an instance of App\Entities\Lead, array given, called in D:\wamp64\www\projects\laraveldemo\crmapp-crud\app\Http\Controllers\LeadController.php on line 108`

How can i solve this issue? Can anyone provide solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you pass the array of inputs instead of model.
You have function `prepareData` inside the repo, so you can use it to prepare the model.

```
$lead = $this->leadRepo->prepareData($input);
$this->leadRepo->create($lead);
```

**UPD**

```
  /**
   * Class LeadRep
   * @package App\Repository
   */
   class LeadRep 
   {
      /**
       * @param $data
       * @return Lead
       */
       public function prepareData(array $data): Lead
       {
          $lead = new Lead();
          $lead->setLeadName($data['lead_name']);
          $lead->setLeadStatus($data['lead_status']);
          $lead->setLeadDescription($data['lead_description']);
        
          return new $lead;
       }
   }
```

Comment: I used this code,but shows error -  An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO lead (lead_name, lead_status, lead_description) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'lead_name' cannot be null

Comment: You use `Doctrine ORM` and have to check how to create the model properly. As I understand, the problem in `new Lead($data);`

Comment: I changed controller function like below, public function store(Request $storeRequest)
{
    $storeRequest->validate([
        'lead_name' => 'required',
        'lead_status' => 'required',
        'lead_description' => 'required'
    ]);

    $lead = new Lead();
    $lead->setLeadName($storeRequest->get('lead_name'));
    $lead->setLeadStatus($storeRequest->get('lead_status'));
    $lead->setLeadDescription($storeRequest->get('lead_description'));

    $this->leadRepo->create($lead);

    return $this->sendResponse($lead, 'Lead created successfully.');
}

Answer (score 0):

```
$lead = $this->leadRepo->create(new LeadRep($lead));
```

You must pass an instance of a model you are creating.

Comment: it returns this error when use instance of model - Class 'App\Http\Controllers\LeadRep' not found

Answer (score 0):

I changed controller function like below, then added this line in top of controller file - `use App\Entities\Lead;` ,then it worked.

```
public function store(Request $storeRequest)
{
    $storeRequest->validate([
        'lead_name' => 'required',
        'lead_status' => 'required',
        'lead_description' => 'required'
    ]);

    $lead = new Lead();
    $lead->setLeadName($storeRequest->get('lead_name'));
    $lead->setLeadStatus($storeRequest->get('lead_status'));
    $lead->setLeadDescription($storeRequest->get('lead_description'));

    $this->leadRepo->create($lead);

    return $this->sendResponse($lead, 'Lead created successfully.');
}
```